# How to properly proportionate the sactter plot dots for an extreme dataset range in Apache ECharts?

Tags: echarts

I have a dataset that contains many symbol size data. However, the range of this symbol size dataset may be too large ( larger than 100k or smaller than 10). As a result, in the scatter plot, the size of the dots will vary greatly, and even interfere with the X-axis and Y-axis. How to make these dots as small as possible without affecting the view?

I try to use a function like sqrt() function to deal with it, but it does not work.[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdq0x.png)

```
{
name: values_entity[i],
type:'scatter',
data: data[i],
symbolSize: Math.sqrt(symbolsize[i]),
color : '#e8a435'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to use [proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)) but if you don't want to compute coefficients by yourself try to [d3.scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale): read [great](https://www.d3indepth.com/scales/) [explanation](https://observablehq.com/@d3/introduction-to-d3s-scales?collection=@d3/d3-scale) and look at [few examples](https://observablehq.com/collection/@d3/d3-scale).

[image]